# what is the event in magento 2 when store configuration save?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

what is the event that is triggered after the save config action is performed in magento 2 Stores - Configuration, and how to write a simple observer method after the save is done.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Following event are fire after System->configuration save.

admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section} -> here $section is 'general' etc.

Here is an example for 'admin_system_config_changed_section_general' event.
**etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="admin_system_config_changed_section_general">
        <observer name="custom_admin_system_config_changed_section_general" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\ConfigObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

and observer class is "[Vendor][Module]\Observer\ConfigObserver"

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class ConfigObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param Logger $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        //$this->logger->info($observer->getWebsite());
        //$this->logger->info($observer->getStore());
    }
}
```

You can do this same thing using plugin.
Create di.xml "etc/di.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="admin_system_config_save_plugin" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\ConfigPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And Plugin class '[Vendor][Module]/Plugin/ConfigPlugin.php'

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;


class ConfigPlugin
{
    public function aroundSave(
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        // your custom logic
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

**Note:**

**`'admin_system_config_changed_section_general'`** this event dispatch with 2 argument **(website and store)**. 
So If you need more data like configuration fields values then you should go with 2nd solution(plugin).

Comment: I have tagged the question as magento 2, the answer is for magento 1 isn't?

Comment: You should add 'Magento2' keyword in your question, tag is not enough.

Comment: Ok, I have edited that, and thought of "Stores -> Configuration" would make sense instead of "System -> Configuration".

Comment: answer edited for Magento2

Comment: I am getting this error when saving the configuration "Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Monolog\Logger::info() must be of the type array, string given" Also where can I check the log informations

Comment: $observer->getWebsite() -> it's string type, so you need to pass this as an array

Comment: changed as array but it prints                                                                          [2016-04-04 09:22:11] main.INFO: Config Website: [""] []
[2016-04-04 09:22:11] main.INFO: Config Store: [""] []

Comment: Okay, it's working fine thanks for solution +1

Comment: I think I missed something. the issue is I am not getting the Store or website code when I save it from "default config" , but while on "Main website" or "default store view" I get Id 1 for store: ["1"], Do we need to create separate observer for store_edit.

Comment: 'admin_system_config_changed_section_general' this event dispatch with 2 argument (website and store). So If you need more data then you should go with 2nd solution(plugin)

Comment: If you get any value for store or website then config save their scope wise, otherwise it's save as a default scope

Comment: default scope returns empty values ?

Comment: yes. check more Magento\Config\Model\Config::save()

Comment: @SohelRana How can one do for `custom_section` I getting an error:  `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file .../app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml:
Element 'event', attribute 'name': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'admin_system_config_changed_section_vendor_module' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z_]+'.`

Comment: Hi, can you please help me this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300048/magento2-3-2-could-not-load-sales-channels-for-stock

Comment: How to get the config value?

Answer (score 4):

**If you want to change or filter current configuration value**, use below way with event `admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section}`

For example, my system.xml like and I want to filter `faq_url` value at the time of saving the config.

```
<section id="faqtab" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>General Configuration</label>
        <field id="faq_url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>FAQ Url</label>
        </field>
    </group>
</section>
```

Create `adminhtml/events.xml`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="admin_system_config_changed_section_faqtab">
        <observer name="custom_admin_system_config_changed_section_faqtab" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ConfigChange"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create `ConfigChange.php`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/ConfigChange.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface;

class ConfigChange implements ObserverInterface
{
    const XML_PATH_FAQ_URL = 'faqtab/general/faq_url';

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * ConfigChange constructor.
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param WriterInterface $configWriter
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        WriterInterface $configWriter
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->configWriter = $configWriter;

    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $faqParams = $this->request->getParam('groups');
        $urlKey = $faqParams['general']['fields']['faq_url']['value']; //Current faq_url value, Here you can filter current value
        $this->configWriter->save('faqtab/general/page_title', $urlKey);
        return $this;
    }
}
```