# save data from a module if save config buton is click in admin configuration

Tags: magento2, system-config, ifconfig

save data from a module in database if save config button is click in admin configuration. Basically I want to disabled a module if disabled from admin. Actually disable functionality is not working. So I trying disabled module pro grammatically I have created a controller with update query but this works when I hit the controller in front end. Basically My query disable module from general but my query will disable from advance/advance.

**Path of controller - Vendor/Module/Controller/index/index.php**

**function in controller that I trying to update :-**

```
public function execute()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('core_config_data'); 
   echo $isEnabled = $this->helperData->isEnable();

   if ($isEnabled==1) {
        //gives table name with prefix

        //Select Data from table
        echo $sql = "Update " . $tableName . " Set value = 0 where path ='advanced/modules_disable_output/Vendor_Module'";
        $connection->query($sql); 

        }

        //return $result->setData($methods);

    else {
        echo $sql = "Update " . $tableName . " Set value = 1 where path ='advanced/modules_disable_output/Vendor_Module'";
        $connection->query($sql); 

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want to do by either using observer or plugin as follows ;

Following event are fire after **System->configuration** **Save**.

**`admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section} ->`** here **`$section`** is **`'general'`** etc.

Here is an example for **`'admin_system_config_changed_section_general'`** event.

**etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="admin_system_config_changed_section_general">
        <observer name="custom_admin_system_config_changed_section_general" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\ConfigObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

and observer class is **"[Vendor][Module]\Observer\ConfigObserver"**

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class ConfigObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param Logger $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        //$this->logger->info($observer->getWebsite());
        //$this->logger->info($observer->getStore());
    }
}
```

You can do this same thing using plugin.
Create **di.xml** **"etc/di.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="admin_system_config_save_plugin" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\ConfigPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And Plugin class **'[Vendor][Module]/Plugin/ConfigPlugin.php'**

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;


class ConfigPlugin
{
    public function aroundSave(
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        // your custom logic
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Reference : [what is the event in magento 2 when store configuration save?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109148/what-is-the-event-in-magento-2-when-store-configuration-save)