# What is the event observer for system config page load in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, event-observer, system-config

We know that we can use **custom_admin_system_config_changed_section_general** for system config page save event. But is there any observer to the config page load event? Thanks.

Comment: there is no such event "custom_admin_system_config_changed_section_general "exists in magento 2 have you ever used this?

Comment: Yup, i am referring to here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109148/what-is-the-event-in-magento-2-when-store-configuration-save

Comment: ok i checked the above link **admin_system_config_changed_section_general** this is the event and you written above event **custom_admin_system_config_changed_section_general** this is just a name of observer that can be any name you write.

Comment: @subhas - did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @subhas did you find any solution for this?