# Magento 2 clear particular block cache

Tags: magento2, cache, block-cache

I have a block that displays a product grid with SKUs mention in admin system configuration and I have provided cache lifetime for that block as 3600 sec. It works perfectly fine.

Now when admin makes the changes in SKUs list in admin configuration it does not reflect the updated version immediately. How can I clear that particular block cache after admin saves the SKUs list?

Comment: you should clear the config cache by command or by admin panel

Comment: @ASQ, but why should someone clear config cache if I want to just flush cache for this particular block?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution:

In your custom block, provide a cache tag for your block by assigning `cache_tags` a unique value for your block.

e.g. in my case, I will set the tag as **cache_tags[] = 'custom_skus'**

**Or** you can implement `IdentityInterface` in your custom block and then override `getIdentities` method, which will return array of tags.

e.g.

```
public function getIdentities()
{
    return ['custom_skus_block'];
}
```

Now, you can observe the save after of admin config and clean the tags using 
`$this->_cacheManager->clean($tags);`. Refer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109148/what-is-the-event-in-magento-2-when-store-configuration-save) for event of admin config save.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the cacheManager is the  Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface

Answer (score -2):

Blocks can be set as non-cacheable by setting the cacheable attribute false in layout XML files. For example

```
<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="false" />
```

Pages containing such blocks are not cached.

Also check How do disable caching of custom block

A single `cacheable="false"` will disable Full Page Caching for the whole page, making the pages sourcing from that layout file extremely slow! Check https://inviqa.com/blog/how-full-page-cache-works-magento-2

Comment: this will not set the cache for the block; I want cache for block, I just need a way where I can just flush the cache for the particular block. Thanks!